# Angular 4 Scroll Element Offset Top Value

Tags: angular, scroll, offset

In jQuery element.offset().top gives on fixed element current position from the document top. When I'm scrolling down it grows up when scrolling up the offset top value decreses.

Now I need the same behavior in Angular 4, but I'm something missing, my offset top value is still the same.

Please see the attached Plunker: https://embed.plnkr.co/3sDzpRcJMEN6lndw4MUB

```
 @Component({
  selector: '[my-app]',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>There is document top</h2>
      <div class="fixed-box" #fixedBox>
        <p>I'm fixed box</p>
        <p>I wanna know my offset from the document top (not viewport) in every scroll step</p>
        <p>My current position from the document top is: {{ fixedBoxOffsetTop }}px</p>
        <p>My current position from the document top is: {{ fixedBoxOffsetTopOtherMethod }}px</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App implements OnInit {
  fixedBoxOffsetTop: number  = 0;
  fixedBoxOffsetTopOtherMethod: number = 0;

  @ViewChild('fixedBox') fixedBox: ElementRef;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  @HostListener("window:scroll", [])
  onWindowScroll() {
    this.fixedBoxOffsetTop = this.fixedBox.nativeElement.offsetTop; // This value looks like init value and doesn't change during scroll
    this.fixedBoxOffsetTopOtherMethod = this.fixedBox.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().top; // The same result as offsetTop
  }
}
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: You probably want to include the code in the body of your question. That link will certainly expire one day, leaving this question bereft of meaning.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You missed `window` and `document` offsets:

```
const rect = this.fixedBox.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect();
this.fixedBoxOffsetTop = rect.top + window.pageYOffset - document.documentElement.clientTop;
```

**[Forked Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/iQsYjHm0cwskF8xGmW53?p=preview)**

Comment: That's still not catering for window resizing... ;-)

Comment: @JGFMK He does not listen `resize` event. See this https://plnkr.co/edit/PLZfad6kQZuHR3qAqxWk?p=preview

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/Z0cSqqJJXWw6dpPeHMbs?p=preview - this does and outputs it initially. I think there is a way to  bind multiple events to a handler too btw -  https://github.com/TheLarkInn/angular2-multievent-bindings-plugin/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Learnt something there - didn't realise you could more than one  HostListener on a single method...

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for.

It's a pitty that you need for that two lines instead of one word.

If somebody want one word, there is custom function:

`  /**
   * Return element coordinates relative to document
   * @param element
   * @returns {number}
   */
  getCurrentOffsetTop(element: ElementRef) {
    const rect = element.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect();
    return rect.top + window.pageYOffset - document.documentElement.clientTop;
  }`

Answer (score -1):

There is my method for that:

```
getCurrentOffsetTop(element: ElementRef) {
  const rect = element.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect();
  return rect.top + window.pageYOffset - document.documentElement.clientTop;
}
```